# Else statement not working and idk why

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

My else statement where I have the header going back to test.php page isn't working and I don't have any idea why  but the if/true statement is working fine  and sending the person to the passengerHome.php page when they entered the correct credentials

```
<?php
    //Feedback variable to update user of system status
        $feedback= "";
    //retrieve the details from the POST Global Variable
      $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];


    validate($user, $pass);
    if($feedback != ""){
      Header("Location:../presentation/passengerLogin.php?feedbackMsg=$feedback");
    }else {//check the database to see if the username and password combination matches
        //clean and format the data
            sanitize($user);
            sanitize($pass);
            //include connection string
            include("../data/dbConnection.php");

                if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT  commuteType, status, passengerID FROM tblPassenger WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"))
                //bind parameters for markers
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $user, $pass);
                                //execute query
                                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                                //bind value holders to result set
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,  $ct, $status, $passenger);
                                if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
                    {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['commuteType'] = $ct;
                        $_SESSION['status'] = $status;
                        $_SESSION['passengerID'] = $passenger;
                        if ($ct == "passenger" && $status == 1 && $passenger != "") {
                            Header("Location: ../presentation/passengerHome.php");
                        }else{
                            Header("Location: ../presentation/test.php");
                        }


                    }

    }


    //Function to SANITIZE (Clean) datax`
    function sanitize($data){
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
      $data = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $data = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $data = filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

      //for,at data for storage (maintain uniformity)
      $data = strtolower($data);
      $data = ucfirst($data);
    //validate($first, $last, $gen, $a, $user, $pass, $em, $add);
      //finally... return the cleaned and formatted data
      return $data;
    }//end sanitize function



      function validate($userVal, $passVal){
            global $feedback;

        if($userVal == null || $userVal == ""){
          $feedback .= "Username required<br/>";
        }else {
          $feedback .= "";
        }
        if($passVal == null || $passVal == ""){
          $feedback .= "Password required<br/>";
        }else {
          $feedback .= "";
        }
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: `global $feedback;` very bad paractise, using global variables in a function. Why not? `$feedback = validate($userVal, $passVal)`;

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written

**$ct = "passenger"**

which is **assignment statement** if condition, **it is always true**, therefore else block is not executed

Comment: Yea I already changed it to == already but when I put in the wrong credentials it sends me to the logic page

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$ct = "passenger"
```

in your else statement, which is not a comparison. Make it

```
$ct == "passenger"
```

Comment: Yea i didn't saw thank you for letting me know  but Im still having the problem.

Comment: You also never set the $feedback variable some value, so you're not entering in the first "else" section. Check that aswell.

Comment: Aite imma check it out

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake:

`if ($ct = "passenger" && $status == 1 && $passenger != "") {`

It should be 
`if ($ct == "passenger" && $status == 1 && $passenger != "") {`

Comment: Yea i didn't saw thank you for letting me know  but Im still having the problem.

Comment: did you print these values `$ct  , $status   $passenger ` to check their value? I mean to say  are you sure this `if`condition is satisfied?